# Pytest: Passing on multiple parameters to a fixture

Tags: pytest

I would like to use a flexible fixture for a data call that can be reused across the test suite. For this purpose I like to ideally pass on more than on parameter. However the code fragment below generally works only for one parameter:

```
@pytest.fixture
def getData(request):
    """Variable data query"""
    data_detail = request.param
```

In the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html) there is no hint that more than one parameter may work, e.g. such as:

```
@pytest.fixture
def getData(request):
    """Variable data query"""
    data_detail = request.param[0]
    time_detail = request.param[1]
```

Does anyone have a hint how to build a pytest fixture to which several parameters / arguments may be passed on?

Answer (score 11):

You can use a tuple or a dict as the fixture parameter:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def tuple_params(request):
    yield sum(request.param)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("tuple_params", [(1, 2, 3)], indirect=True)
def test_tuple_params(tuple_params):
    print(tuple_params)  # 6


@pytest.fixture
def dict_params(request):
    yield f"{request.param['a']}_{request.param['b']}"


@pytest.mark.parametrize("dict_params", [{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}],
                         indirect=True)
def test_dict_params(dict_params):
    print(dict_params)  # foo_bar
```

Generally, the parameter can be any object, so you can always put your fixture parameters in a suitable object.

With a tuple or a list parameter, you can also access the values per index as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

- So we I have class user with name and age
- Class constructor expecting name and age parameters
- In fixture we have sent parmas as [("swapnil-1",23),("swapnil-2",25)]In the fixture body while instantiating user class,
  user(request.param[0],request.param[1]) is used as request.param[0] is passed for name, and request.param[1] for age

```
class user:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
class Test_parameterize:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class',params=[("swapnil-1",25),("swapnil-2",27)])
    def dummy_usr_obj(self, request):

         obj = user(request.param[0],request.param[1])
         yield obj
         obj = None

    def test_user(self,dummy_usr_obj):

        print("--user name :  {0} user age {1} ".format(dummy_usr_obj.name, dummy_usr_obj.age))
```